# Decorator implementation around xarray.open_dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

If you would like to download some grib data for yourself, the script below will pull girb data from the google api over a date range at an hourly interval.

### Extract some hrrr grib2 data

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterator
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import copyfileobj
import warnings

from requests import Session, HTTPError
import pandas as pd


def google_api_hrrr_grib2_data(start: datetime, end: datetime) -> Iterator[str]:
    """
    url generator function for googleapis high-resolution-rapid-refresh dataset
    """
    base_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/high-resolution-rapid-refresh/"
    date_range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="h")
    yield from base_url + date_range.strftime("hrrr.%Y%m%d/conus/hrrr.t%Hz.wrfnatf00.grib2")

def download_hrrr(start: datetime, end: datetime, path: Path):
    """
    iterate over urls and save files to a Path directory
    """
    # request context manager
    with Session() as session:
        # iteratate over the generator function
        for url in google_api_hrrr_grib2_data(start=start, end=end):
            # add the filename to the path object
            save_to = path / ".".join(url.replace("hrrr.", "").split("/")[-3:])

            try:
                # make a http get request to the url
                res = session.get(url, stream=True)
                # on non 200 status code raise HTTPError
                res.raise_for_status()
                # save the file to the directory
                with save_to.open("wb") as fileout:
                    copyfileobj(res.raw, fileout)
                print("grib2 file saved at ", save_to)

            except HTTPError:
                warnings.warn(f"Warning: failed to download {url}")



data_hrrr = Path("data/hrrr/")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_hrrr(start=datetime(2022, 6, 15), end=datetime(2022, 6, 16), path=data_hrrr)
```

### Transform the data into python objects

This environment requires `xarray`, `cfgrib`, and ideally `dask`.

> dask is not required but speeds up the process.
>
> > if not using `dask` the `chunks` argument to `xr.open_dataset` will need to be set to `None`.

I wanted to try and make use of pythons `decorator` function.  I have used it from several other libraries but never really implemented one to this extent myself.

The standard dimensions for every parameter are `latitude, longitude, & valid_time`

#### griblib/common.py

```py
from typing import Callable, Literal, overload, Iterator
import xarray as xr

class GribBase:
    def __init__(self, files: list[str]) -> None:
        self._file_list = files

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}.propertys({1})".format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            ", ".join(attr for attr in self.__dir__() if not attr.startswith("_")),
        )

    def iterfiles(self)->Iterator[str]:
        yield from self._file_list

def filter_by_level(level: str):
    """decorator"""

    lat_lon_vt = {"latitude", "longitude", "valid_time"}

    def generator(grib:GribBase, **kwargs):
        for file in grib.iterfiles():
            with xr.open_dataset(
                file,
                engine="cfgrib",
                **kwargs,
            ) as ds:
                if lat_lon_vt.issubset(ds.coords):
                    yield ds.drop_vars(coord for coord in ds.coords if coord not in lat_lon_vt)

    def func_wrapper(func: Callable[["GribBase"], dict[str, str]]):
        """the func() is the returned value from the function"""

        @overload
        def key_filter(
            grib: "GribBase",
            name: str = ...,
            stepType: Literal["max", "instant"] = ...,
            shortName: str = ...,
            standard_name: str = ...,
            **kwargs:str,
        ) -> xr.Dataset:
            ...

        def key_filter(grib: "GribBase", **kwargs: str) -> xr.Dataset:
            """the wrapped func"""

            default_return = func(grib)

            if not default_return:
                filter_by_keys = {"typeOfLevel": level} | kwargs
            else:
                filter_by_keys = {"typeOfLevel": level} | default_return | kwargs

            objs = generator(
                grib,
                filter_by_keys=filter_by_keys,
                chunks={},
            )
            return xr.concat(objs, dim="valid_time")

        return key_filter

    return func_wrapper
```

I went ahead an omitted the abc `Docstring` class

with the decorator function I can specify the level argument that I want to filter grib data and set an optional default return value.  This is only necessary for certain variables.

#### griblib/hrrr.py

```py
import xarray as xr
from typing import Literal
from griblib.common import GribBase, filter_by_level
## from griblib._abc import DocStrings



## class ByLevel(GribBase, DocStrings):
class ByLevel(GribBase):
    @filter_by_level("atmosphere")
    def atmosphere(self):
        """returns all attributes at with the shared `atmosphere` level"""

    @filter_by_level("isothermal")
    def isothermal(self):
        """returns all attributes at with the shared `isothermal` level"""
        return {"stepType": "instant"}

    @filter_by_level("hybrid")
    def hybrid(self):
        """returns all attributes at with the shared `hybrid` level"""

    @filter_by_level("heightAboveGroundLayer")
    def height_above_ground_layer(self):
        """returns all attributes at with the shared `heightAboveGroundLayer` level"""


class HRRR(ByLevel):
    def geopotential_height(self, level="isothermal") -> xr.Dataset:
        match level:
            case "isothermal":
                return super().isothermal(name="Geopotential Height", stepType="instant")
            case "hybrid":
                return super().hybrid(name="Geopotential Height")

    def pressure(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Pressure")

    def unknown(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="unknown")

    def mixing_ratio(self, kind: Literal["rain", "snow", "cloud"] = "rain") -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name=f"{kind.title()} mixing ratio")

    def graupel(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Graupel (snow pellets)")

    def particulate_matter(self, kind: Literal["fine", "coarse"] = "fine") -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name=f"Particulate matter ({kind})")

    def fraction_of_cloud_cover(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Fraction of cloud cover")

    def temperature(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Temperature")

    def specific_humidity(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Specific humidity")

    def u_component_of_wind(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="U component of wind")

    def v_component_of_wind(self):
        return super().hybrid(name="V component of wind")

    def vertical_velocity(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Vertical velocity")

    def turbulent_kinetic_energy(self) -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().hybrid(name="Turbulent kinetic energy")

    def derived_radar_reflectivity(self, step_type: Literal["max", "instant"] = "instant") -> xr.Dataset:
        return super().isothermal(name="Derived radar reflectivity", stepType=step_type)
```

### main.py

```py
from glob import glob

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import xarray as xr

from griblib.hrrr import HRRR


def open_gribs(files: list[str]) -> HRRR:
    return HRRR(files if isinstance(files, list) else [files])


def scatter_plot(ds: xr.Dataset, parameter: str, **kwargs):
    columns = {
        v.attrs["GRIB_shortName"]: v.attrs["long_name"].lower().replace(" ", "_") for v in ds.data_vars.values()
    }
    for vt, df in ds.to_dataframe().rename(columns=columns).groupby("valid_time"):
        plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
        ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        plt.figure(vt.value)

        ax.coastlines("50m")

        ax.set_extent(
            [
                *df["longitude"].agg(["min", "max"]),
                *df["latitude"].agg(["min", "max"]),
            ],
            ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        )

        df.plot(
            kind="scatter",
            y="latitude",
            x="longitude",
            c=parameter,
            ax=ax,
            alpha=np.where(df[parameter] > 0, 0.2, 0),
            cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"),
            s=0.25,
            figsize=(16, 12),
            **kwargs,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hrrr = open_gribs(glob("data/hrrr/*.grib2")[:2])
    hrrr.derived_radar_reflectivity().pipe(scatter_plot, parameter="derived_radar_reflectivity")
```

[image: radar-image-one]
[image: radar-image-two]